# Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure Namespace - Cim classes

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm using new new `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` classes to handle WMI, but I've encountered a stumbling block, and can't find any information on how to work around this using these classes without having to fall back to using `System.Management.ManagementObject`.

Basically, `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` doesn't expose any methods for objects, which is what I'm having difficulties with.

I've retrieved a `CimClass` object, let's call it `Win32_Process` , called the property `.CimClassProperties["Handle"]` to get the `Handle` property and `.Qualifiers` to retrieve a list of qualifiers for the `Handle` property.

At this stage I'd like to delete one of the qualifiers, but there are no methods exposed that allow such a thing.

Using `Microsoft.Management.ManagementObject` namespace, I could get a `ManagementClass` object, again `Win32_Process` for the sake of the argument, call `.Properties["Handle"].Qualifiers.Remove(<qualifierName>)` to remove the qualifier, but no idea how to do this using the new classes and there's no info out there that I can find.

**EDIT**: I did some digging and found that to invoke methods on CIM objects you use the `CimSession` class, using either `CimSession.InvokeMethod` or `CimSession.InvokeMethodAsync` methods and was able to use it to invoke a method of a `CimClass` and of a `CimInstance`, but it does not appear to be able to invoke methods of any object outside of those two, from what I can see. Is this me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it is not possible to modify the Qualifiers. Reason is it is read only property. Also, if you want something to do in code, they take the data in list or string array and manipulate them.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned, if using `System.Management.ManagementObject` this is doable.

Comment: I guess when class itself is not exposing the write function, how is it possible using API? I am bit confused here.

Comment: Because *every* WMI object can be both created and deleted, so those don't have to be exposed by the WMI class, they're inherited by the parent class. When you create your own WMI class, you also don't create a create method, yet you can create instances of that class...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but I have found myself in a similar situation with trying to change Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort Printer IP Addresses and Names, which are also ReadOnly. I did come across some articles that refer to wbemtest.exe. This utility can be used to make changes like this, but use extreme caution as it is a WMI-Object editor and can break your system. This link will explain it better https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/08/04/hey-scripting-guy-how-do-i-use-wmi-with-windows-powershell-to-return-information-about-properties/